# Microsoft's WordPad - File Reformatting

Tags: wordpad

I found [this](http://blog.animalswithinanimals.com/2008/08/databending-and-glitch-art-primer-part.html) tutorial on "glitching" image files by opening/saving them in WordPad.

This left me wondering: what kind of reformatting do the pre-Vista and Vista/7 versions of WordPad apply to binary documents they open, that could produce this effect?